# unable to run query "AzureActivity" using Azure Monitor Log

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am facing issue while running "AzureActivity" query in Azure Monitor Log. I am using free trail subscription and I created a vm and trying to run query but facing issue. Please find below screenshot.

[image: error image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225441/discussion-on-question-by-affish-mohammad-unable-to-run-query-azureactivity-us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an [Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-create-workspace). Then go to azure portal -> your vm -> in the Activity log page, click the `Diagnostic settings` button -> then in the Diagnostic settings, click the `Add diagnostic setting` button -> then you can send all the logs to the `Log Analytics workspace`. At last, you can try to query in that `Log Analytics workspace`.